# How to solve several issues with train fucntion in R?

Tags: r, cross-validation, k-nearest-neighbour

I have to solve some problems with knn algorithm  and corss validation. I will post my code and the text of the exercise later so you will be able to understand. At the end of the script R returns this error + warning :

You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column

**Error: pre-processing methods are limited to: BoxCox, YeoJohnson, expoTrans, invHyperbolicSine, center, scale, range, knnImpute, bagImpute, medianImpute, pca, ica, spatialSign, ignore, keep, remove, zv, nzv, conditionalX, corr
In addition: Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column**

How can I fix it? Thanx in advance

here the exercise text and code:

***Consider a simple classifier (say K-Nearest Neighbours with k=7) applied to some two-class data:
1. Starting with 5000 predictors (assume standard normal) and 50 samples, find the 100 predictors
having the largest correlation with the class labels (assume binomial(0.5)); 
2. Then apply KNN, using only these 100 predictors; 
3. Illustrate the implications of doing feature selection before or within 10-fold cross validation on
accuracy***

```
library('caret', quietly = TRUE)

set.seed(202)

n=50

pred=5000

y=rbinom(size=1,n=50,p=0.5)



x=matrix(0,nrow=n,ncol=pred)

for(j in 1:pred){

x[,j]=rnorm(n)

}



corr.1 <- cor(x,y)

kept=100

highest=x[,highest[1:kept]]

datas=data.frame(y,highest)

datas[[1]] <- as.factor(datas[[1]])

names(datas) <- tolower(names(datas))

#Here only one knn as e.g.

KNN <- train(datas$y~.,method='kknn',tuneGrid =expand.grid(kmax =7),trControl= trainControl(method ='cv',number = 5),metric = 'Accuracy',data = datas)
```